# Using ExternalCodeComp as the single comp and OpenMDAO concept

Tags: openmdao

I am very much attracted to the idea of using the OpenMDAO. However I am not sure if it is worthwhile to use OpenMDAO in an optimization scenario where I use an external code as a single component and nothing else.

Is there any difference between the implementation using an optimizer available in SciPy versus the aforementioned openmdao implementation.

Or any difference between that and implementation of similar approach in some other language like matlab optimization toolbox etc?

(Of course the way optimizers are implemented may differ but i mean conceptually am i taking advantage of OpenMDAO with this approach?)

As far as I read the articles; openMDAO is powerful in cases where multiple components ''interact'' with each other and "global derivatives"" are obtained?
Am I taking advantage of openMDAO by using single ExternalCodeComp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just a single ExternalCodeComp would not be using the full potential of OpenMDAO. There would still be some advantages, because the ExternalCodeComp handles a lot of file wrapping details for you. Additionally, there are often details in an optimization, such as adding constraints, the will commonly require additional components. In that case you might use an [ExecComp](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/features/building_blocks/components/exec_comp.html) to add a few additional calculations. 
Lastly, using OpenMDAO would allow you to potentially grow your model in the future to include other disciplines.

If you are sure that you'll never do anything other than optimize the one external code, then OpenMDAO does reduce down to a similarly functionality to using the bare pyoptsparse, scipy, or matlab optimizers though. In this corner case, OpenMDAO doesn't bring a whole lot to the table, other than the ease of use of the ExternalCodeComp.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand which formulation is useful. 
What if i packed everything inside the Externalcodecomp 
ExternalCodeComp => 1 input --> 2 outputs (constraint and obj)
Or
ExternalCodeComp => 1 input --> 3 outputs (obj) and 2 extra for execcomp inputs
ExecComp=> 2 inputs --> 1 output (previous constraint)

So the second formulation is taking advantage of openmdao global derivative approach but I am not sure if it will help to converge better?

Comment: It might help it to converge a little better, because the exec comps use complex step to compute more accurate derivatives. Your external code comp will be finite-differenced most likely. But it probably won't make a huge difference. The only exception would be if your external code is actually an implicit analysis with its own solver. Then you could use ImplicitExternalCodeComp and the FD would be a bit more accurate in that case.